# save web form data on crash

Tags: html, forms, web

I have a big web from i need to save data locally ( on client ) , so if the user browser crash or energy  off the user will be able to recover it i.e. save the current state of dom element with inout values  .
Is there any recommended solution like a JS library or browser plugin ( for chrome )  ?

Comment: have you looked into [jSotrage](http://www.jstorage.info/)

Comment: lscache is a very simple solution: https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache

Answer (score 0):

If your users are definitely using Chrome you can rely on [HTML5's local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage).

As this is fairly new there are few libraries for using it yet, here is one:

http://www.jstorage.info/

Answer (score 0):

Html5 has client side storage:
See [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/) and [here](http://geeknizer.com/html-5-client-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

i Found this very use-full lib. https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus